# Found number of rows before a value changes with a group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this one

```
CREATE TABLE Levels
    ([userid] int, [counter1] int, [counter2] int, [date] datetime)
;
```

The `counter2` is an incremental value. The `date` is just the datetime the row was created. The `counter1` is a field that can take different integer values. And the `userid` the id of the user.

This is an example of the data. You can find a bigger example with two users in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ae44c/1)

```
| userid | counter1 | counter2 |                 date |
|--------|----------|----------|----------------------|
|    123 |        6 |       42 | 2010-07-31T00:12:28Z |
|    123 |        6 |       43 | 2010-11-20T00:11:15Z |
|    123 |        6 |       44 | 2011-03-12T00:15:07Z |
|    123 |        5 |       45 | 2011-07-02T01:11:09Z |
|    123 |        5 |       46 | 2011-10-22T00:24:18Z |
|    123 |        5 |       47 | 2012-02-10T23:51:54Z |
|    123 |        5 |       48 | 2012-06-01T23:43:26Z |
|    123 |        5 |       49 | 2012-09-21T23:43:59Z |
|    123 |        4 |       50 | 2013-01-11T23:52:43Z |
|    123 |        4 |       51 | 2013-05-03T23:49:25Z |
|    123 |        4 |       52 | 2013-08-23T23:48:24Z |
|    123 |        3 |       53 | 2013-12-14T00:01:20Z |
|    123 |        3 |       54 | 2014-04-04T23:45:45Z |
|    123 |        4 |       55 | 2014-07-25T23:44:34Z |
|    123 |        5 |       56 | 2014-11-14T23:46:11Z |
```

What I try to do is to count how many times the `counter1` has the same value before it changes. Why the rest of the questions I found in stackoverflow didn't work?

- The `counter1` field can get the same value multiple times later on, which I don't want to count as the same case.
- I am working in SQL Server 2008 and `LAG` function is not available

The desired result for the full example in sqlfiddle is

```
| userid | counter1 | count |
|--------|----------|-------|
|     123|         6|      3|
|     123|         5|      5|
|     123|         4|      3|
|     123|         3|      2|
|     123|         4|      1|
|     123|         5|      1|
|     123|         6|      2|
|     123|         5|      5|
|     123|         4|      2|
|     123|         5|      1|
|     123|         4|      5|
|     123|         5|      5|
|     345|         6|      2|
|     345|         6|      9|
```

Comment: Why are you using unsupported software?

Comment: It's not my decision :( @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  Fortunately, you can use the difference of row numbers:

```
select userid, counter1, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by userid order by counter2) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by userid, counter1 order by counter2) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by userid, counter1, (seqnum - seqnum_2)
order by userid, min(counter2);
```

Note:  This assumes that the ordering is based on `counter2`. If it is really based on `date` then you can use that column instead.

Why this works is a little tricky to explain.  But if you look at the results from the subquery, you will see how the difference between the two `row_number()` values is constant when `counter1` has the same value on adjacent rows.

Comment: This is working. I need to wait for a couple of minutes before I accept the answer. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

YOu don't actually need `LEAD` and `LAG` here, however, getting to a supported version of SQL Server, where `LAG` (and `LEAD`) are available should be priority.

```sql
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(123,6,42,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2010-07-31T00:12:28Z')),
                (123,6,43,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2010-11-20T00:11:15Z')),
                (123,6,44,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2011-03-12T00:15:07Z')),
                (123,5,45,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2011-07-02T01:11:09Z')),
                (123,5,46,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2011-10-22T00:24:18Z')),
                (123,5,47,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2012-02-10T23:51:54Z')),
                (123,5,48,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2012-06-01T23:43:26Z')),
                (123,5,49,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2012-09-21T23:43:59Z')),
                (123,4,50,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2013-01-11T23:52:43Z')),
                (123,4,51,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2013-05-03T23:49:25Z')),
                (123,4,52,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2013-08-23T23:48:24Z')),
                (123,3,53,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2013-12-14T00:01:20Z')),
                (123,3,54,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2014-04-04T23:45:45Z')),
                (123,4,55,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2014-07-25T23:44:34Z')),
                (123,5,56,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2014-11-14T23:46:11Z')))V(userid,counter1,counter2,date)),
Grps AS (
    SELECT userid,
           counter1,
           counter2,
           date,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY [date]) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid,counter1 ORDER BY [date]) AS Grp
    FROM YourTable)
SELECT userid,
       counter1,
       COUNT(*)
FROM Grps
GROUP BY userid,
         counter1,
         Grp;
```